# Box2D collision between dynamic body

Tags: libgdx, box2d, body

I'm implementing Box2D for my 2d top down LIBGDX game and i have some struggle with two dynamic body.
Currently, my two bodies are created that way :

```
    BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
    bodyDef.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;
    bodyDef.position.set(this.x, this.y);
    this.body = world.createBody(bodyDef);
    PolygonShape collider = new PolygonShape();  
    collider.setAsBox(16, 16);
    FixtureDef fDef = new FixtureDef();
    fDef.density = 0f;
    fDef.friction = 0f;
    fDef.restitution = 0f;
    fDef.shape = collider;
    body.createFixture(fDef);
    body.setUserData(this);
    collider.dispose();
```

So basicly, no rotation, no friction and no restitution. Also, my world have a gravity of 0 (since it's a 2d top down game, i don't that want them to fall). When player 1 collide with player 2, player 2 is moved backward like it was push but i don't want that. I want it to stay where he is, blocking the path to player 1 but he can also move.

Is there a way to do that ?
I have looked for some tips like catching collision with the contact listener but i don't know what to do in the preSolve method.

I'd like some help, thanks !

Comment: I think what you want to do is set your Body isKinematic to true.

Comment: What @Jon said except in Libgdx you want `bodyDef.type = BodyType.KinematicBody`.

Comment: Now that my BodyType is KinematicBody, they doesn't even collide. Plus they don't collide against walls :/